# Determine if string is base64-encoded twice

Tags: php, regex, base64

Is there any way to determine if a string is base64-encoded twice?

For example, is there a regex pattern that I can use with `preg_match` to do this?

Comment: I think you got the down-votes because the question was a little misdirected and required a lot of effort to answer; putting a lot of effort into answering a question that should not have been asked angers people. The next time you ask a question, try and avoid the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 13):

***(Practical answer.)*** Don't use regex. Decode your string using [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)'s optional `$strict` parameter set to `true` and see if it matches the format you expect. Or simply try and decode it as many times as it permits. E.g.:

```
function base64_decode_multiple(string $data, int $count = 2) {
    while ($count-- > 0 && ($decoded = base64_decode($data, true)) !== false) {
        $data = $decoded;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

***(Theoretical answer.)*** Double-base-64-encoded strings *are* regular, because there is a finite amount of byte sequences that properly base64-encode a base64-encoded message.

You can check if something is base64-encoded *once* since you can validate each set of four characters. The last four bytes in a base64-encoded message may be a special case because `=`s are used as padding. Using the regular expression:

```
<char>           := [A-Za-z0-9+/]
<end-char>       := [A-Za-z0-9+/=]
<chunk>          := <char>{4}
<end-chunk>      := <char>{2} <end-char>{2} | <char>{3} <end-char>
<base64-encoded> := <chunk>* <end-chunk>?
```

You can also determine if something is base64-encoded *twice* using regular expressions, but the solution is not trivial or pretty, since it's not enough to check 4 bytes at a time.

*Example:* "QUFBQQ==" base64-decodes to "AAAA" that base64-decodes to three NUL-bytes:

```
$ echo -n "QUFBQQ==" | base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 4141 4141                                AAAA

$ echo -n "AAAA" | base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 0000 00                                  ...
```

At this point we could enumerate all double-base64-encodings where the base64-encoding is 4 bytes within the base64 alphabet ("AAAA", "AAAB", "AAAC", "AAAD", etc.) and minimize this:

```
<ugly 4> := QUFBQQ== | QUFBQg== | QUFBQw== | QUFBRA== | ...
```

And we could enumerate the first 4 bytes of all double-base64-encodings where the base64-encoding is 8 bytes or longer (cases that don't involve padding with `=`) and minimize that:

```
<chunk 4> := QUFB | QkFB | Q0FB | REFB | ...
```

One partition (the pretty one) of double-base64-encoded strings will not contain `=`s at the end; their lengths are a multiple of 8:

```
<pretty double-base64-encoded> := <chunk 4>{2}*
```

Another partition of double-base64-encoded strings will have lengths that are multiples of 4 but not 8 (4, 12, 20, etc.); they can be thought of as pretty ones with an ugly bit at the end:

```
<ugly double-base64-encoded> := <chunk 4>{2}* <ugly 4>
```

We could then construct a combined regular expression:

```
<double-base64-encoded> := <pretty double-base64-encoded>
                         | <ugly double-base64-encoded>
```

As I said, you probably don't want to go through all this mess just because double-base64-encoded messages *are* regular. Just like you don't want to check if an integer is within some finite interval. Also, this is a good example of getting the wrong answer when you should have been asking another question. :-)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to implement the multiple decode using java instead of php? I think I'm facing a similar problem with a server that returns doubly-encoded base64 data but I haven't been able to double decode properly. You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797789/base64-encoded-image-is-null-when-decoded?noredirect=1#comment123378162_69797789.