# base64 encoded image is null when decoded

Tags: android, cordova, base64, android-bitmap

I keep getting `null` when I try to decode a base64 image in an android app. The app downloads the image from a server and I get the input stream of the request (which contains the base64 data). Now when I try to convert the input stream into a bitmap, I get `null`. This is a snippet of my code (from a fork of [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps), the relevant file is [`src/android/plugin/google/maps/AsyncLoadImage.java`](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/blob/bdb7af4730857a6b51662a8cfd180f6c5a3dce35/src/android/plugin/google/maps/AsyncLoadImage.java#L279):

```
        HttpURLConnection http = null;
        http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("GET");
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        byte[] imageBytes = buffer.toByteArray();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
        // Resize
        int newWidth = (int)(mWidth * density);
        int newHeight = (int)(mHeight * density);
        if (newWidth > 2000 || newHeight > 2000) {
          float rationResize;
          if (newWidth >=  newHeight) {
            rationResize = 2000.0f / ((float) newWidth);
          } else {
            rationResize = 2000.0f / ((float) newHeight);
          }
          newWidth = (int)(((float)newWidth) * rationResize);
          newHeight = (int)(((float)newHeight) * rationResize);
        }

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, options);
        Boolean bitmapIsNull = myBitmap == null; // `true`, why??

        if (myBitmap == null) {
          // now try decoding the encoded data
          String imageStr = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
          InputStream strStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageStr.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
          myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(strStream);
          bitmapIsNull = myBitmap == null; // still `true`, why??
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, middleX - options.outWidth / 2, middleY - options.outHeight / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
        myBitmap.recycle();
```

I've compared the output of the input stream (encoded as a string i.e. the `imageStr` variable) to that of an image that works, and I noticed that the content is not "typical" base64 content when it doesn't work. To put it simply, this is the value of `imageStr` when it doesn't work:

```
"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"
```

It doesn't work in the browser either after I prepend `data:image/webp;base64,` to it. Now when I decode that string in javascript (using [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)), I get this string:

```
"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"
```

This string looks like "typical" base64 content and it works **in the browser** when I prepend `data:image/webp;base64,` to it.

So I then add this logic before the `canvas.drawBitmap` step above:

```
          String decodedStr = new String(imageBytes);
          InputStream decodedStrStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(decodedStr.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
          myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(decodedStrStream);
```

`decodedStrStream` is the same string that works in the browser. `myBitmap` is finally not null, yet the image still doesn't show.

So ultimately my question is how can I convert the input stream to an image that shows?

### Update

In response to @blackapps' suggestion, my new code that handles the null image is now this:

```
        if (myBitmap == null) {
          byte [] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
          myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length, options);
          bitmapIsNull = myBitmap == null; // now `false`, but image is a gray square
        }
```

However the image is now gray. I'll update this after trying "double" decoding.

Comment: `byte[] imageBytes = buffer.toByteArray();` Well you better call that base64Bytes and base64 decode them to image bytes before using BitmapFactory.

Comment: @blackapps please can you expand on that? I'm guessing you mean `byte[] base64Bytes = buffer.toByteArray();` but how would I then convert that to image bytes? Thanks. :)

Comment: Try: `byte [] imageBytes = Base64.decode(base64Bytes, Base64.DEFAULT));`

Comment: When I decode the first base64 string (the one that doesn't work) on https://www.base64decode.org/ I get another base64 string. And after decoding that I get binary data that begins with `RIFF ��WEBPVP8X`, so it seems to be double encoded.

Comment: @jps yes that's what I got too. I think I was tripped up on how to decode twice because I tried a few things but they didn't seem to work properly. I'll confirm the outcome of blackapps's suggestion in some minutes.

Comment: @blackapps now I get a gray box instead of my image, any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Maybe you should double decode? And please post your new code. Test: after base64 decoding save the byte array to file. Then you can inspect what you have with a lot of apps.

Comment: @blackapps I've added the code that shows the gray image. I'll do a new build of the app with your file and double decode suggestions and report the outcomes.

Comment: `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` You should set that to false . (The second time, before you call decode to obtain a bitmap.)

Comment: `However the image is now gray. `         Confusing remark. We see nothing and your bitmap is null. Thats it. `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` will do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238773/discussion-between-uche-ozoemena-and-blackapps).

Comment: Sorry, no chatting.

Comment: Okay sure thing. Do you mean that I should set `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` and still do double decoding? My build hit a snag so I haven't been able to test the double decoding by itself.

Comment: @blackapps sorry I just reviewed the code I posted and I realize it doesn't show that `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` is already present in my actual code.